# java.io.FileNotFoundException for .cache file in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

My project is IntelliJ was all fine and suddenly I started getting the following error

```
Loading project definition from C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\codingjedi\code_related\code\frontend\web\project
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\codingjedi\code_related\code\frontend\web\project\target\config-classes\$999b06365add2ae5fadc.cache (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I am unable to compile my code due to this. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

worked after removing (by renaming) the `project/target` directory and rebuilt the project. It created a new `target` directory in `project` and things are working again

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have caching issues in IntelliJ, you can try to use the `Invalidate Caches / Restart` action in the `File` menu. Please read the displayed messages carefully ("WARNING: Local History will be also cleared.").

Another thing you could try: `Rebuild Project` in the `Build` menu.

Comment: thanks. I tried both of these but none worked. Eventually had to delete `project/target` and rebuild the project